# python logs get suppressed

Tags: python, logging, tornado

My tornado application is using some legacy modules written many years back. Those modules are configured to log out things with root logger. The issue I am facing is that whenever I import those modules the logs printed by the tornado(i.e. tornado.access, tornado.application, etc..) get suppressed.

Here is how I invoke my server

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""Basic run script"""

from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
ioloop.install()

import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.options
import tornado.web
import tornado.autoreload
from tornado.options import options
import tornado.web

from grace_server.application import MyApplication
from settings import settings

def main():
    app = MyApplication(settings)
    app.listen(options.port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here is the definition of the `tornado.Application`

```
import collections, zmq, os
import logging, re
import pickle, json
from datetime import datetime
from functools import partial

from zmq.eventloop.zmqstream import ZMQStream
from zmq.eventloop import ioloop

from tornado import web
from tornado.log import LogFormatter, app_log, access_log, gen_log
from jupyter_client import MultiKernelManager

from legacy_module import api
from legacy_module.util.utils import get_env

from urls import url_patterns


ioloop = ioloop.IOLoop.current()

class MyApplication(web.Application):

    def __init__(self, settings):
        self.init_logging()
        self.connections = collections.defaultdict(list)
        self.kernels = {}
        self.listen_logs()
        web.Application.__init__(self, url_patterns, **settings)


    def init_logging(self):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger('MyApplication')
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


    def broadcast_message(self, message):
        connections = self.connections.keys()
        for conn in connections:
            conn.write_message(message)

    def multicat_message(self, filter_, message):
        connections = self.connections.keys()
        connections = filter(connections)
        for conn in connections:
            conn.write_message(message)

    ...
    ...
    ...
```

This is how `logging` is configured in my `legacy_module`

```
import os, json
import logging, logging.config
from contextlib import contextmanager

from kombu import Connection
from terminaltables import AsciiTable

from legacy_module import resources
from legacy_module.resources.gredis import redis_tools
from legacy_module.core import versioning
from legacy_module.util.utils import get_logger_container, get_env

from legacy_module.resources.databases.mongo import MongoDatabaseCollection

DB_COLLECTION_OBJECT = MongoDatabaseCollection()

LOGGING_FILE = os.path.join(os.environ['legacy_module_HOME'], 'config', 'logging.config')
logging.config.fileConfig(LOGGING_FILE)
LOGGER = logging.getLogger()

...
...
...
```

This is how `logging.config` looks.

```
[loggers]
keys = root

[handlers]
keys = consoleHandler

[formatters]
keys = simpleFormatter

[logger_root]
level = DEBUG
handlers = consoleHandler

[handler_consoleHandler]
class = StreamHandler
level = DEBUG
formatter = simpleFormatter
args = (sys.stdout,)

[formatter_simpleFormatter]
format = %(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
datefmt =
```

This is how normal logs looks like

```
2017-09-28 02:40:03,409 MyApplication DEBUG    init_logging done
2017-09-28 02:40:13,018 MyApplication DEBUG    Authenticating
```

But When I comment out the import for `legacy_module` from `MyApplication`, I can see `tornado.access` logs

```
2017-09-28 02:40:03,409 MyApplication DEBUG    init_logging done
2017-09-28 02:40:13,017 tornado.access INFO     304 GET / (172.20.20.3) 1.79ms
2017-09-28 02:40:14,264 tornado.access INFO     304 GET /api/login (172.20.20.3) 0.75ms
2017-09-28 02:40:13,018 MyApplication DEBUG    Authenticating
```

so the `logging` configurations of my `legacy_module` is some how suppressing the logs by the `tornado`.
How can I fix this, I need these logs.

Answer (score 0):

First, in yourlegacymodule, remove the `logging.config.fileConfig(LOGGING_FILE)` call and replace `LOGGER = logging.getLogger()` with `LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)`.

Then you may want to make sure you have at least the root logger properly configured (don't know what you get in tornado for logging config so check the docs).

As a more general note: this logging configuration in a library module is the perfect example of logging antipattern - the whole point of the `logging` package is to decouple logger's use (from within library code) from logging config which should be left to the application using the library code and should be configurable per application *instance*. FWIW note that your own `MyApplication.init_logging()` is also an antipattern - you shouldn't hardcode the logger's level in your code, this should be done using a per-instance config (cf how django uses the `settings` module to configure logging).

**Update:**

I'd have to dig into tornado's code to give you an exact detailed answer, but obviously the `logging.config.fileConfig()` call in yourlegacymodule overrides tornado's own configuration.

> are my configs done in init_logging get overridden by the root logger ?

The only thing you currently "configure" (and which you shouldn't) in `init_logging` is the "MyApplication" logger's level, this has no impact on which loggin handler is used (=> where your logs are sent) etc.

> how can I prevent them ?

This was the very first part of my answer...

Comment: Thanks for the answer @bruno, I will keep that anti-pattern in my mind now on, but can you explain to me why I can't see the logs, are my configs done in `init_logging` get overridden by the root logger if so how can I prevent them? or the logs are getting streamed to somewhere else?